# How to strech a column while centering their children

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to expand a column horizontally while keeping the children (an icon and a text) in the center.

When I use CrossAxisAlignment.center it doesn't mathes its parents width. So I tried CrossAxisAlignment.stretch.

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.help),
    Text('Please help!'),
  ],
),
```

Here the text was aligned left even though the icon is centerd.
I do not understand this and a solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's simple, you just need to add a `align: TextAlign.center` in your `Text`, and the text would be centered. `Text` is taking whole width, but `TextAlign.left` by default.

Answer (score 1):

I found a `hack` might not the exact solution but works for me.

there might be other solutions

Added a `SizedBox` box widget with `width` because we need to center `horizontally`.

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.help),
            Text('Please help!'),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity, // it will take entire available device width
              height: 0,
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried wrapping column in a container and setting width to double.infinity?

```
Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.help),
            Text('Please help!'),
        ],
    ),
)
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner solution? This is just a workaround, isn't it?

Comment: yes :P its a workaround, you can also checkout fittedbox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4Uehk3_wlY

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.help,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            ),
            Text('Please help!'),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do is:

```
Center( // it helps column stretch
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // it helps child stay in center
    children: ...,
  )
)
```